# React with server side variables

Tags: dom, client, reactjs, server

I'm rendering out components that have properties with liquid strings. These components are being rendered on the server and picked back up again in the client. Essentially I'm using the DOM as a data store. I'm debating on methods of where to store the data. I need the component to render out valid markup to the server for SEO. But I don't need to pick back up the variable like I am here with `this.refs.variantId.getDOMNode()`. I could for instance set the `variantId` to a global client side javascript variable somewhere higher then this code in essence something like `var variantId = "{{ product.variants[0].id }}";`.

This component will render to a string and be placed within a template file on a server, the server will process that HTML come across the `{{ product.variants[0].id }}` variable and turn it into something like `1058477584`. My component needs to reach into the existing DOM for itself and pull the value out.

```
var React = require("react");
var $ = require("jquery");

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var variantId = this.refs.variantId.getDOMNode().value.trim();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/cart/add.js",
      method: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "id": variantId,
        "quantity": this.props.quantity,
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // emit cart added event
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        // emit error event (cart added)
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
      quantity: 1,
      variantId: "{{ product.variants[0].id }}",
      buttonText: "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="buyButton">
        <form action="/cart/add" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value={ this.props.quantity } />
          <input type="hidden" name="id" ref="variantId" value={ this.props.variantId } />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-holstee">{this.props.buttonText}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I'm wondering what people think about rendering components with another templating language as a string property. Does it make sense to store that data anywhere else? I don't have access to a server that can store individual pages. It's all templates so multiple data sources need to be handled by one route.

- Is there a better way to abstract the liquid out of the component?
- Is there a better way to call `DOMNodes` / update all the props to DOMNodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar in my app. I serialize with JSON and put it in a script tag in the DOM

```
<script type="application/json" id="preload-notifications">{{json_encode($preload_notifications)}}</script>
```

Then,

```
var raw = document.getElementById('preload-messaging');

if (raw === null) {
    return ;
}

var data = JSON.parse(raw.text);
```

I use the flux architecture so it's really simple

```
this.dispatch('messaging', {
    messages: data
});
```

But you could can inject it as a prop.

```
React.render(<MessagingContainer messages={data} />, messageDomNode);
```

Whatever you do, I suggest you don't query the DOM inside a React component. Try to pass stuff as props as much as possible.